# SSH Tunnel to establish a connection to server "b" through server "a"

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I've program "p", which gets data from server "b" and which needs a connection to server "b" at port 23500 to run. the problem is that I've to be in network/server "a" to connect to server "b". So how I can establish a ssh tunnel to run program "p"?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ssh -l remoteuser -L 23500:localhost:23500 remotehost
```

Then let connect program "p" to localhost on port 23500.

The syntax of -L is as follows:

```
[bind_address:]port:host:hostport
```

That means you can also alter the port on your side, e.g. make your local host listen on, say, port 80 while the connection is piped to port 23500 on the remote host

```
$ ssh -l remoteuser -L 80:localhost:23500 remotehost
```

If you want to bind on a port lower than 1024 you'll need root privileges.